# Open source photo viewer for IPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

Is there any open source photo viewer for Iphone, which functionality will be similar to standard Iphone application?

Answer (score 12):

Check out [MWPhotoBrowser](http://github.com/mwaterfall/mwphotobrowser) - a simple and easy to use photo viewer for iOS:

MWPhotoBrowser can display one or more images by providing either UIImage objects, or URLs to files, web images or library assets. The photo browser handles the downloading and caching of photos from the web seamlessly. Photos can be zoomed and panned, and optional (customisable) captions can be displayed. The browser can also be used to allow the user to select one or more photos using either the grid or main image view.

[image: MWPhotoBrowser Screenshots]

Comment: This looks great but is there a thumbnail gallery to go with it?

Comment: There's currently no thumbnail gallery with the library.

Comment: Can i add this without pod file?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [EGOPhotoViewer](https://github.com/enormego/PhotoViewer).