# ALAsset Image Size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, alassetslibrary

Given an ALAsset that represents a photo, is it possible to retrieve the size of the photo (height and width) without loading the image into a UIImageView and also without using the aspectRationThumnail method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just a note:
iOS 5.1 introduces a new property dimensions for an ALAssetRepresentation instance. This returns a CGSize structure with the dimensions of the original image and might be the best solution for this problem in the future.

Cheers,

Hendrik

Comment: Yes, that's much faster than either of the methods I suggested.  May I ask how the `dimensons` property was discoverable, since it's not mentioned in the ALAssetRepresentation Class Reference, even for iOS 5.1?

Comment: It's mentioned here in the API differences:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS51APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011328

Answer (score 6):

```
float width = asset.defaultRepresentation.dimensions.width;
float height = asset.defaultRepresentation.dimensions.height;
```

it fast, stable, and gives the actual dimensions. I've used it with ALAsset of videos.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler way to access the image size is through `[ALAssetRepresentation metadata]`.  On the images I tested on, this `NSDictionary` contained keys named `PixelWidth` and `PixelHeight`, which were `NSNumber` objects with the values you'd expect.

However, there seem to be no particular guarantees about the exact keys you'll find, so make sure your app can deal with cases where those keys aren't in the metadata.  Also see [iOS ALAsset image metadata](http://sarofax.wordpress.com/2011/07/10/alasset-image-metadata/) for some cautions about speed and thread safety.

### Comparison

I tested both methods - loading the image data in CGImageSourceRef or reading the metadata - on my iPad's entire asset library.  Both methods returned the same sizes to within FLT_EPSILON.  Apart from 2 outliers which took double time, the run times out of 16 repetitions were very similar:

```
Method                     | Mean time +/- 95% confidence
Size from CGImageSourceRef |    0.1787 +/- 0.0004
Size from metadata         |    0.1789 +/- 0.0015
```

So, neither method has a performance benefit.  It is entirely possible that the metadata dictionary is constructed on demand by reading the image data.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

This didn't work as originally offered, as noted in the comments.  I've fixed it, but it now loads all the image data, which the OP was trying to avoid.  It still avoids the additional, and still worse step, of decompressing the data into an image.

1. Get the `defaultRepresentation` of the ALAsset.
2. Get the data for the ALAssetRepresentation.
3. Use an adaptation of [this handy sizeOfImageAtURL](https://gist.github.com/1744633) function.  Thank you, shpakovski.

The code below represents the steps above.

```
// This method requires the ImageIO.framework
// This requires memory for the size of the image in bytes, but does not decompress it.
- (CGSize)sizeOfImageWithData:(NSData*) data;
{
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeZero;
    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef) data, NULL);
    if (source)
    {
        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:(NSString *)kCGImageSourceShouldCache];

        NSDictionary *properties = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary*) CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options);

        if (properties)
        {
            NSNumber *width = [properties objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth];
            NSNumber *height = [properties objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight];
            if ((width != nil) && (height != nil))
                imageSize = CGSizeMake(width.floatValue, height.floatValue);
        }
        CFRelease(source);
    }
    return imageSize;
}

- (CGSize)sizeOfAssetRepresentation:(ALAssetRepresentation*) assetRepresentation;
{
    // It may be more efficient to read the [[[assetRepresentation] metadata] objectForKey:@"PixelWidth"] integerValue] and corresponding height instead.
    // Read all the bytes for the image into NSData.
    long long imageDataSize = [assetRepresentation size];
    uint8_t* imageDataBytes = malloc(imageDataSize);
    [assetRepresentation getBytes:imageDataBytes fromOffset:0 length:imageDataSize error:nil];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:imageDataBytes length:imageDataSize freeWhenDone:YES];

    return [self sizeOfImageWithData:data];
}

- (CGSize)sizeOfAsset:(ALAsset*) asset;
{
    return [self sizeOfAssetRepresentation:[asset defaultRepresentation]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put that up. When I am doing it, I'm getting ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithURL CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource failed with error code -11 for some reason. Wonder if ALAsset urls are compatible with this?

Comment: @CoDEFRo: Yes, I'm afraid I didn't actually test the step where it took the NSURL for an ALAsset object.  It seems there's no way to load data from the URL, so I'm not sure what you're supposed to do with it.  I've edited to provide code that does work, and also suggested an alternative answer.

Comment: I think the sizeOfImageWithData method is incorrect - in my tests, I need to also look at the Orientation flag. When I take an image in portrait mode, I get width/height inverted and an Orientation value of 6 (mirrored portrait mode). Anyway - I think it needs to look at kCGImagePropertyOrientation as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
float width = CGImageGetWidth(asset.defaultRepresentation.fullResolutionImage);
float height = CGImageGetHeight(asset.defaultRepresentation.fullResolutionImage);
```

or same for `asset.defaultRepresentation.fullScreenImage`...

Comment: Works terrible on big images