# How to select Multiple images from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios5, xcode4

In my application, I have to select more images ie; up to 3 images from library or capture of images.

Comment: you can not use the multiple image in UIImagepickercontroller u have to use assetlibrary for it

Comment: https://github.com/Gk19011994/BRImagePickerSwift-like-whatsapp-

Comment: Can multi select using Apple API PHPickerViewController from 2020, iOS 14.

Comment: For SwiftUI - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57110290/how-to-pick-image-from-gallery-in-swiftui/75006863#75006863

Answer (score 310, accepted):

You can't use `UIImagePickerController`, but you can use a custom image picker. I think [`ELCImagePickerController`](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController) is the best option, but here are some other libraries you could use:

**Objective-C**
[1. ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController)
[2. WSAssetPickerController](https://github.com/w5mith/WSAssetPickerController)
[3. QBImagePickerController](https://github.com/questbeat/QBImagePickerController)
[4. ZCImagePickerController](https://github.com/iamzcc/ZCImagePickerController)
[5. CTAssetsPickerController](https://github.com/chiunam/CTAssetsPickerController)
[6. AGImagePickerController](https://github.com/arturgrigor/AGImagePickerController)
[7. UzysAssetsPickerController](https://github.com/uzysjung/UzysAssetsPickerController)
[8. MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser)
[9. TSAssetsPickerController](https://github.com/tomkowz/TSAssetsPickerController)
[10. CustomImagePicker](https://github.com/cspnanda/CustomImagePicker)
[11. InstagramPhotoPicker](https://github.com/wenzhaot/InstagramPhotoPicker)
[12. GMImagePicker](https://github.com/guillermomuntaner/GMImagePicker)
[13. DLFPhotosPicker](https://github.com/nicnocquee/DLFPhotosPicker)
[14. CombinationPickerController](https://github.com/opendream/CombinationPickerController)
[15. AssetPicker](https://github.com/taruntyagi697/AssetPicker)
[16. BSImagePicker](https://github.com/mikaoj/BSImagePicker)
[17. SNImagePicker](https://github.com/NarekSafaryan/SNImagePicker)
[18. DoImagePickerController](https://github.com/donobono/DoImagePickerController)
[19. grabKit](https://github.com/pierrotsmnrd/grabKit)
[20. IQMediaPickerController](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQMediaPickerController)
[21. HySideScrollingImagePicker](https://github.com/wwdc14/HySideScrollingImagePicker)
[22. MultiImageSelector](https://github.com/chengyifly/MultiImageSelector)
[23. TTImagePicker](https://github.com/siqin/TTImagePicker)
[24. SelectImages](https://github.com/iceVeryCold/SelectImages)
[25. ImageSelectAndSave](https://github.com/xiefangzhenz/ImageSelectAndSave)
[26. imagepicker-multi-select](https://github.com/wuyuedefeng/imagepicker-multi-select)
[27. MultiSelectImagePickerController](https://github.com/DerekSelander/MultiSelectImagePickerController)
[28. YangMingShan(Yahoo like image selector)](https://github.com/yahoo/YangMingShan)
[29. DBAttachmentPickerController](https://github.com/d0ping/DBAttachmentPickerController)
[30. BRImagePicker](https://github.com/BrammanandSoni/BRImagePicker)
[31. GLAssetGridViewController](https://github.com/XuYanci/GLAssetGridViewController)
[32. CreolePhotoSelection](https://github.com/NirmalsinhRathod/CreolePhotoSelection)

**Swift**
[1. LimPicker (Similar to WhatsApp's image picker)](https://github.com/limhowe/LimPicker) 
[2. RMImagePicker](https://github.com/maxdrift/RMImagePicker)
[3. DKImagePickerController](https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController)
[4. BSImagePicker](https://github.com/mikaoj/BSImagePicker)
[5. Fusuma(Instagram like image selector)](https://github.com/ytakzk/Fusuma)
[6. YangMingShan(Yahoo like image selector)](https://github.com/yahoo/YangMingShan)
[7. NohanaImagePicker](https://github.com/nohana/NohanaImagePicker)
[8. ImagePicker](https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker)
[9. OpalImagePicker](https://github.com/opalorange/OpalImagePicker)
[10. TLPhotoPicker](https://github.com/tilltue/TLPhotoPicker)
[11. AssetsPickerViewController](https://github.com/DragonCherry/AssetsPickerViewController)
[12. Alerts-and-pickers/Telegram Picker](https://github.com/dillidon/alerts-and-pickers)

Thanx to @androidbloke,
I have added some library that I know for multiple image picker in swift.
Will update list as I find new ones.
Thank You.

Comment: Lovely list.  Seems to be lacking swift support though.

Comment: Superb ! ELCImagePickerController is the best option. Thanks Dilip

Comment: UzysAssetsPickerController is super i like it a lot

Comment: I have worked out with DKImagePickerController. Follow the steps and install via cocoa pods. Add the following to get the selected photo's urls fo further use. Hope it helps !   

        let pickerController = DKImagePickerController()
        pickerController.sourceType = .Photo
        pickerController.didSelectedAssets = { [unowned self] (assets: [DKAsset]) in
            println("didSelectedAssets")
            println(assets)

            for(var i = 0; i<(assets.count); i++){
                print(assets[i].url)

                self.PickedArray .addObject(assets[i].url!)

            }

Comment: @AlvinGeorge, Sorry i have not personally used this library, but sure someone with knowledge of this library will give us answer, also you can create separate question for this issue, that way your issue has better exposure in community.

Comment: @Dilip  Which one will be best for SWIFT

Comment: @G.Abhisek i have not used any Swift library till yet from list, You can suggest in comment after experimenting with some.

Comment: @Dilip DKImagePickerController I have used this and till now it works great as it has less number of classes & more over it is being updated frequently and the owner is very responsive to problems.

Comment: none of above supports swift 3 at least till current date

Comment: @iPhone6 DKImagePickerController supports swift3

Comment: @nidhin yes it supports now.

Comment: I worked on  BSImagePicker. It works fine in Swift 3. I have added following code while installing the Pod File 

`post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
target.build_configurations.each do |config|
config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
end
end
end`

but it does not allow for video selection. if any idea about it. Please do let me known.

Comment: Most of the projects are dead, or with less than 100 stars. I only need a plain simple picker. I found QBImagePicker is the closest to the iOS system look and feel.

Comment: Hello any updates to this list that supports swift 4 and is not depreciated? Seems like most of them are already dead as @x.y commented above.

Comment: OpalImagePicker is BEST!!!

Comment: @Dilip Which library support burst photo? Plz let me know asap. Thank in advance

Comment: You don't need libraries to achieve this, simply store the last tapped ImageView in a property in your ViewController, explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52239275/7343596

Comment: Do any of these support iCloud download on demand like the normal UIImagePickerController?

Comment: If you are interested I make one for SwiftUI: https://github.com/moifort/swiftUI-photo-library-picker

Comment: Hey. I found (but didn't test) one more library: https://github.com/awkward/Tatsi

Comment: You guys can use PHPickerViewController.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phpickerviewcontroller