# Three images using image picker

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am building an app that allows user to add three pictures to three`UIImageViews`
I added three buttons, for instance, when a user clicks on button one he should be able to add an image to`UIImageView` 1
but the image did not come to the`UIImageView` and I did not find any solution

sample of code:

```
 @IBAction func imageOneBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

        func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]){
            let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
            imageViewOne.image = selectedImage
            imageViewOne.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
            picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You use Custom Imagepicker for Taking three image.

Comment: https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController

Comment: actually this is for objective-C and what i really want is not to pick multiple images at the same time, but to choose one by one. anyway, thank you for the answer and if you know anything that could help me please tell

Comment: see this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756899/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-uiimagepickercontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem, and this is the answer for anyone who may want to use it

```
   import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate  {


@IBOutlet weak var oneImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var twoImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var threeImg: UIImageView!

var num=0;

func config() {
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }

 @IBAction func oneBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    num = 1
    config()
 }


 @IBAction func twoBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    num = 2
    config()
 }


 @IBAction func threeBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    num = 3
    config()
 }


 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]){
    let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage;

    if num == 1 {  // switch can be used here
        oneImg.image = selectedImage;
     } else if (num == 2) {
        twoImg.image = selectedImage
     } else if (num == 3) {
        threeImg.image = selectedImage
     }
     picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be correct.

```
let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
```

Try removing the exclamation mark (!).

Try using `imageViewOne.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit`

Also try using `var` instead of `let selectedImage`

In general Try this code

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
var selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
imageViewOne.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
imageViewOne.image = selectedImage
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but for the "!" mark I cannot remove it as I am using version 6.3 ... and I have changed the codes as you said but still :( is the problem that I can't use image picker function inside another method? in my case the button function??

Comment: you cant write a method inside another method