# how to use multiple image picker in iOS with swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making dating app.
as you know, users need to register multiple pictures in dating app.

so i got how to use 1 image picker in one view.

but i don't know how to add multiple image picker.

i know i can only use only one

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {  
}
```

and

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion:nil)
}
```

so i cant find solution for multiple imagepicker view.

my failed code is below.

```
import UIKit

class RegisterPicture : UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {


@IBAction func pick1(sender: AnyObject) {

    let picker1 = UIImagePickerController()

    picker1.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum

    picker1.allowsEditing = true

    picker1.delegate = self

    self.presentViewController(picker1, animated: false, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func pick2(sender: AnyObject) {

    let picker2 = UIImagePickerController()

    picker2.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum

    picker2.allowsEditing = true

    picker2.delegate = self

    self.presentViewController(picker2, animated: false, completion: nil)
}

@IBOutlet var picture1: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var picture2: UIImageView!

func imagePickerController(picker1: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    picker1.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion : nil)
    self.picture1.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

}

func imagePickerController(picker2: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    picker2.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion : nil)
    self.picture2.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

}


func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker1: UIImagePickerController) {

    picker1.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion:nil)

}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker2: UIImagePickerController) {

    picker2.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion:nil)

}
}
```

Comment: you can find a great answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756899/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-uiimagepickercontroller

I ran into your same situation and found the good answer here.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone searching for this in 2020, Apple introduced `PHPickerViewController` in iOS14. Here's the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phpickerviewcontroller

And the WWDC introduction that explains its usage:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10652/

Answer (score 3):

You can't select more than one image with UIImagePickerController. You either have to make your own custom image picker that can or use a 3rd party's like this [one](https://github.com/mikaoj/BSImagePicker).

Comment: then I would just copy how some of the libraries do it like this one: https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController/blob/master/DKImagePickerController/DKImagePickerController.swift

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func btnTrophy1Action(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //GIVE TAG TO YOUR BUTTON
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        self.senderTag = sender.tag
        pickerOpen(sender: sender)
    }

@IBAction func btnTrophy2Action(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //GIVE TAG TO YOUR BUTTON
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        self.senderTag = sender.tag
        pickerOpen(sender: sender)
    }

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            //BASED ON THE TAG SAVE IMAGE TO PARTICULAR IMAGE PICKER
            if self.senderTag == 101 {
                //TROPHY 1
                self.imgTrophy1.image = image
                self.isTrophy1Selected = true
            } else if self.senderTag == 102 {
                //TROPHY 2
                self.imgTrophy2.image = image
                self.isTrophy2Selected = true
            } else {
                //TROPHY 3
                self.imgTrophy3.image = image
                self.isTrophy3Selected = true
            }
        }
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is a solution I tried out to address this sort of problem

I used a single image picker then use an enum holding strings to determine which image view gets the image selected by the user.

```
enum selectableImage: String {
        case image1
        case image2
        case image3
    }
```

then on each call of the `imagePickerController`, I assign a variable `var imageSelected = selectableImage.image1` like so.
Then finally in the `imagePickerController`, I used the switched structure like so:

```
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        print("Inside imageController")

        print(info)
        // The info dictionary may contain multiple representations of the image. You want to use the original.

        guard let imagePicked = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
            fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
        }

        // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.

        switch imageSelected {

        case selectableImage.image1:
             image1.image = imagePicked

        case selectableImage.image2:
             image2.image = imagePicked

        case selectableImage.image3:
            image3.image = imagePicked

        }


        // Dismiss the picker.
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use UIImagePickerController, but you can use a custom image picker. I think ELCImagePickerController is the best option, but here are some other libraries you could use:

Objective-C

1. ELCImagePickerController
2. WSAssetPickerController
3. QBImagePickerController
4. ZCImagePickerController
5. CTAssetsPickerController
6. AGImagePickerController
7. UzysAssetsPickerController
8. MWPhotoBrowser
9. TSAssetsPickerController
10. CustomImagePicker
11. InstagramPhotoPicker
12. GMImagePicker
13. DLFPhotosPicker
14. CombinationPickerController
15. AssetPicker
16. BSImagePicker
17. SNImagePicker
18. DoImagePickerController
19. grabKit
20. IQMediaPickerController
21. HySideScrollingImagePicker
22. MultiImageSelector
23. TTImagePicker
24. SelectImages
25. ImageSelectAndSave
26. imagepicker-multi-select
27. MultiSelectImagePickerController
28. YangMingShan(Yahoo like image selector)
29. DBAttachmentPickerController
30. BRImagePicker
31. GLAssetGridViewController
32. CreolePhotoSelection

Swift

1. LimPicker (Similar to WhatsApp's image picker)
2. RMImagePicker
3. DKImagePickerController
4. BSImagePicker
5. Fusuma(Instagram like image selector)
6. YangMingShan(Yahoo like image selector)
7. NohanaImagePicker
8. ImagePicker
9. OpalImagePicker
10. TLPhotoPicker
11. AssetsPickerViewController
12. Alerts-and-pickers/Telegram Picker