# pick several image in a view from library swift

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I begin swift and I wanted to pick some images from the iPhone library to some UIImageViews.
I used the followed code but my problem is each time  I pick a new image, it placed on the previous UIImageView, not in it own UIImageview.

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
@IBOutlet var img1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var img2: UIImageView!
 @IBAction func addphotofct(sender: UIButton!){



    if (img1.hidden == true){


        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        img1.hidden = false
        img1.userInteractionEnabled = true



    }else  (img2.hidden == true) {


        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        img2.hidden = false
        img2.userInteractionEnabled = true

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
imagePicker.delegate = self
 }

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage1 = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        img1.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        img1.image = pickedImage1
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    func imagePickerController2(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage2 = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        img2.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        img2.image = pickedImage2
    }
```

AS you can see, i created 'img1' and  'img2' as imageView.
when I selected the 2nd image , it delete img1 to replace by img2.
with thte rest of my code, i know 'img2' = 'img2' so the 2nd image is in 'img2' and 'img1' faded away.. i want it both in my view..
how can I fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20756957/6297658

Comment: thank you, i ll try to use ELCImagePickerController. 
but xcode say "use of unresolved identifier "ELCImagePickerController". 
have i to import something more?

Comment: You are writing in swift right? `ELCImagePickerController` is a obj-C written cocoapod , use `DKImagePickerController ` for swift Or you can use a `Bidging Header` for `ELCImagePickerController`

Comment: i cant find it in package manager... and it pick several pictures in the same time ,right? i just want show several picture in my viewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i focused myself on the code and find the way to pick several images not in the same time, but in the `view`.

I just have to transform my `imagePickController` function like that:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

        if (img1.hidden == true){


            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary


              img1.hidden = false
             img1.userInteractionEnabled = true
            img1.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            img1.image = pickedImage


        }else if (img2.hidden == true) {


            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary


            img2.hidden = false
            img2.userInteractionEnabled = true
            img2.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            img2.image = pickedImage

        } else {
            alert("STOP", message:"vous avez atteint la limite de photos possible")
        }


    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```