# How to select multiple images in UIImagepickercontroller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

Can you give some examples for UIImage Picker controller..

```
let title = "Take a new photo or select one from your library"
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: "", preferredStyle: .alert )


    // Create the action.
    let Camera = UIAlertAction(title: "CAMERA", style: .default,  handler:  {
        action in
            if UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType .camera)
            {
                self.present(self.picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

    })

    let Gallery = UIAlertAction(title: "GALLERY", style: .default,  handler: {
        action in
        alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            if UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary)
            {
                self.present(self.picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
    })

    alertController.addAction(Gallery)
    alertController.addAction(Camera)

    // Show alert
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Just enter your question title in google. You will get lots of links.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756899/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: Before posting questions on stackoverflow you must have google first.