# Is it possible to should be able to move the crop square in side a uiimagepickercontroller in camera

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, ios-camera

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCMd0.jpg
```

In the above image how can i should be able to move the crop square, not the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydnor.jpg)

Comment: any one can give the reply

Comment: Not possible with UIImagePickerController , if you need to create overlay or use with help of thirdparty

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik.. Pls give the some examples for that

Answer (score -2):

My advice is to use the library for achieving this. Here you can find the list of libraries for image upload. 
[List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756899/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-uiimagepickercontroller)