# Swift 3 select multiple photos using UIImagePickerController

Tags: swift3, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a `UIImagePickerController` which with it I select a photo from Library, or take a photo with Camera and then show the selected photo in a `UIImageView`. I want to upload this photo later to an API (which still don't know how to upload photos, have never done it).

So what I want is a feature like WhatsApp selecting photos feature which you can select let's say 20 photos and then you can see them. (I mean for my case I only have one `UIImageView` and can only show one photo.

What is the solution? please keep in mind that I want to upload this photos later.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [Ethan Halprin commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500193/swift-3-select-multiple-photos-using-uiimagepickercontroller/45506785#comment77969132_45500193), I used https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker and it solved my issue. It looks really nice and I think the customer will like it :)

Answer (score -1):

I also found [TLPhotoPicker](https://github.com/tilltue/TLPhotoPicker) and [DKImagePickerController](https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController/issues) helpful since the Hyperosolo's [image picker](https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker) is deprecated DKImagePickerController and TLPhotoPicker was a good choice left in swift.Some other references :-

[More helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20756957/6330448)