# Select multiple image from photo library using swift

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, swift4, phphotolibrary

I am new in IOS and i want to select multiple image from photo library using swift4  and get into array of images.Please help me to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select Multiple images from UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756899/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-uiimagepickercontroller)

Comment: **Refer this :** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756899/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3 select multiple photos using UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500193/swift-3-select-multiple-photos-using-uiimagepickercontroller)

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the multiple image in UIImagepickercontroller u have to use assetlibrary for it.

You can use a custom image picker. I think [ImagePicker](https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker) is best for Swift

Comment: This module is deprecated!