# Using a UIImagePicker that only contains photos taken within the app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using source code from apple (SquareCam) and I would like to figure out how I can use the photos taken in that app and see them in a library (like the photos app) without having all the other photos the user has taken elsewhere like in the regular camera. 
I'm not too great at making apps yet so I'm pretty noobish.

I've gotten as far as opening the photo library but nothing else. no viewing individual photos or the options such as emailing, messaging and what not.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can do that. It either all photos or no photos...

Answer (score 0):

You can of course save the photo in your own documents directory and write your own photo viewer - there's quite some code and frameworks around that do most of the job, see e.g. the answers to this so question:

[Open source photo viewer for IPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163847/open-source-photo-viewer-for-iphone)